# How to view the MS-SQL server at UI?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, mssql

How to view the Database MSSQL server database at ui in ubuntu is their any s/w available. I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a graphical UI to a database, take a look at [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

**Universal Database Tool**

Free multi-platform database tool for developers, SQL programmers, database administrators and analysts. Supports all popular databases: MySQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB, SQLite, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server, Sybase, MS Access, Teradata, Firebird, Derby, etc.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

install phpmyadmin

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

https://your_domain_or_IP/phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

I like [DbVisualizer](https://a.slashdotmedia.com/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=35750__zoneid=33050__cb=1f1d4eb36282347e9f34__oadest=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dbvis.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Dsourceforge.com%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dvisitwebsite):

[image]

It also works with many databases, and has a feature to generate schema diagrams as well:

[image]